# UV Editing - Unwrap object and display measurements in the view

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

How can i display the measurements from the 3D-editor in the UV-editor as illustrated in the picture?

[image]

Comment: You can't, the UV editor uses a 0.0 to 1.0 (X Y) or pixel cordinates.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a rather complex workaround for my use case. Hopefully somebody will post once a cleaner solution.
So since I want to print out the unwrapped model with the dimensions to help with a sewing project I came up with this way:

1. I export the model as an SVG file in uv/unwrap (one face at a time)
2. Import the SVG file in QCAD.
3. I scale the dimensions to match the edge the ones in the 3d model
4. Now I can set all the dimensions and angles in QCAD